# Vertical Asymptotes of $f(x) = \frac{\ln(|4x+1|)}{\ln(\sqrt{3x+4})}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to make sure I understand the concept correctly. If I'm trying to find the vertical asymptotes of the following:
$$ f(x) = \frac{\ln(|4x+1|)}{\ln(\sqrt{3x+4})}$$

Do we not care of when $ln(x)$ is not defined, and just evaluate for the denominator being equalling $0$ in which case the only vertical asymptote is $x = -1$, or do we need to be careful? If so, for what do I need to look out?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not actually when the denominator is equal to zero but for finding the vertical asymptote you actually have to find where the denominator approaches 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rational functions, you would be right in thinking that you only need to worry about the denominator.  However, as the logarithmic function carries a vertical asymptote itself (which grows far more quickly compared to the rate of rational functions not near asymptotes), we also have to consider those.

As such, I am sure it would not surprise you to know that the vertical asymptotes of this function are $x=-1$ and $x=-\frac14$.

Comment: Hm, then how come $x = -\frac{4}{3}$ is not a vertical asymptote?

Comment: Values near a vertical asymptote are extremely huge.  When dividing by something extremely huge, the result is something near $0$.

Comment: So basically if I understand it correctly, $x = -\frac{4}{3}$ is basically "swallowed" by the asymptote at $x = -1$? If so, then how can we establish if that's the case or not for other values we compute (to know if they are a vertical asymptote or not without looking at the graph)

Comment: Not exactly (as $-\frac43$ is actually nowhere near $-1$); what suggests to you that $x=-\frac43$ should be a vertical asymptote?

Comment: $ln(\sqrt{3x+4})$ => $3x+4 = 0$ for which the function of $ln(x)$ is undefined?

Comment: Are you familiar the end behaviour of the logarithmic function?  As we get nearer the value what makes the function undefined, its value decreases towards $-\infty$.  As a result, your function will be in the form $$\frac{\text{something}}{-\infty}\to0,$$ which is not indicative of a vertical asymptote.

Comment: Oh wait, so what makes $x = -\frac{1}{4}$ be a vertical asymptote? Because I assume that it applies the same logic of $ln(x)$ being undefined at that point which is apparently wrong

Comment: OH NVM, obviously when $x = -\frac{1}{4}$ the numerator is then $-\infty$, which is then a vertical asymptote.

Comment: You've got it. ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton! :P

Answer (score 0):

It could help to notice that your function's domain of definition is $\;\left(-\frac43,\,\infty\right)\setminus\{-\frac14\}\;$, and also for these values

$$\log\sqrt{3x+4}=\frac12\log(3x+4)$$

so your function is actually

$$f(x)=\frac{2\log|4x+1|}{\log(3x+4)}$$

Since  $\;\log|4x+1|\xrightarrow[x\to-1/4]{}-\infty\;$  and the denominator equals $\;\log13/4\;$ , then $\;x=-1/4\;$ is a vertical asymptote.

And also when the denominator gets close to zero but the numerator doesn't (as then we'd need to check more carefully), and this happens when $\;x\to-1\;$ , which you already had.

In any other value of the domain the function is just the quotient of two well defined, continuous functions and thus continuous itself.